# Connection refused Django requests-module

Tags: python, django, python-requests

i'm trying to send GET request from my Django app to Spring app hosted in my local machine.

I've tested sending requests to another websites outside localhost and it works perfectly. Problem appears when it comes to sending to *http://localhost:port*.

This is function which is sending requests in my Django app. It works for **url1** but doesnt for **url2**.

```py
def send_mail(request):
    url1 = "https://httpbin.org/get"
    url2 = "http://localhost:5000"
    response = requests.get(url2)

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Here's an error that shows wherever i try send request to localhost.

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))